# Como cambiar color de de barra de scroll mat-selection-list angular material

Tags: css, scroll, angular-material

Quiero cambiar el color del scroll de navegacion ponerlo mas pequeño y los bordes curvos, le asigne un id scroll al mat-select y al mat-option pero no funciono, este es mi codigo del html:

```
 <mat-list-item>
                <mat-selection-list>
                  <mat-list-option checkboxPosition="before" *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes">
                    {{shoe}}
                  </mat-list-option>
                </mat-selection-list>
              </mat-list-item>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese es mi estado actual, quiero tenerlo parecido a este :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el css que estoy usando es este :

```
.mat-selection-list {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 145px;
  background: white;
 border-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

para cambiar el diseño del Scroll, tienes que usar la pseudo-propiedad de css `::-webkit-scrollbar` dándole un alto, color, ancho, etc, según como lo quieras.

Te dejo un ejemplo claro de como puedes hacerlo.

**CSS**

```css
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 16px;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #fff;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #babac0;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: none;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
  
<p>What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>

<p>What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>

<p>What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>

<p>What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>

</div>
```

Puedes averiguar mas de esto en:

[W3SCHOOLS](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar) o en [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/).